# rewrite everything to index.php in a subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My doamin points to

```
public_html
```

My index.php is in

```
public_html/webroot/
```

My .htaccess in public_html/

```
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/ [L]
```

which redirects to index.php quite nicely

Now, I would like to redirect

```
domain.com/one/two/three
```

to

```
domain.com/app/webroot/index.php?1=one&2=two$three=3
```

I tried a couple of combinations but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$ webroot/index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.

I should have mentioned that I would like this to work with
domain.com/one/
domain.com/one/two

Also, I loose access to my css file located in
public_html/

Any suggestions?

Comment: For css/js  just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^1/?([^/.]+)/2/([^/.]+)/3/([^/.]+)$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the example i showed above is in apache conf  file. i am not sure about .htaccess, but  you might be able to translate it to .htaccess

Thanks